# Need help using npmv package (nonparametric testing) in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the Bathke package "npmv" in R to run the nonpartest() function on a dataset that I created. In their paper they use their implemented code with provided dataset 'sherry':

```
install.packages("npmv")
library(npmv)
data("sberry",package="npmv")
nonpartest(weight|bot|fungi|rating~treatment,data=sberry,permreps=1000)
```

Which works perfect for their dataset. However, when I try to run it on my csv dataset which has the exact same dimensions, it does not work for some reason and keeps giving me the error "data set not found" and saying the sample size must be at least 2??

Their dataset is as follows:

```
Treatment   Replicate   Weight    Botrytis  Fungi   Phomopsis
Kocide          1       6.9         4.1     17.24   1
Kocide          2       8.3         5.13    5.65    1
Kocide          3       8.4         6.07    8.8     1.5
Kocide          4       7.95        2.72    9.51    1.5
Elevate         1       8.6         1.19    17.06   1
Elevate         2       8.5         0.55    12.86   1
Elevate         3       8.2         0.74    6.76    0.5
Elevate         4       9.5         0.99    1.84    1
V-10135         1       6.2         4.29    4.64    1
V-10135         2       9           1.56    3.03    3
V-10135         3       6.8         0.88    5.6     0
V-10135         4       8.5         2.42    8.66    2
Control         1       7.5         15.6    13.08   1
Control         2       6.7         10.28   14.43   1
Control         3       8.7         13.29   10.92   2.5
Control         4       7.4         18.38   16.03   3
```

while mine is:

```
   Treatment Replicate Weight_Loss Persistent Head_Size Salebarn_Q
    LA 200         1       17.90      14.10     14.25        1.0
    LA 200         2       19.30      15.30      2.56        1.0
    LA 200         3       19.50      16.82      5.80        1.5
    LA 200         4       18.94      12.70      7.51        1.5
    Excede         1       19.60      11.20     14.52        1.0
    Excede         2       19.50      10.54      9.83        1.0
    Excede         3       19.10      10.83      3.82        0.5
    Excede         4       20.40      11.00      0.04        1.0
   Micotil         1       17.30      14.29      1.62        1.0
   Micotil         2       20.00      11.65      0.13        3.0
   Micotil         3       18.10      10.89      2.41        0.0
   Micotil         4       19.50      12.43      5.93        2.0
    Zoetis         1       18.50      25.48     10.08        1.0
    Zoetis         2       17.60      20.12     11.93        1.0
    Zoetis         3       19.70      23.29      7.93        2.5
    Zoetis         4       18.50      28.32     13.08        3.0
```

(Zoetis being my control)

I tried the code

```
data("Cattle", package = "npmv")
nonpartest(Weight_Loss|Persistent|Head_Size|Salebarn_Q~Treatment,data=Cattle,permreps=1000)
```

Any idea how I would be able to return the same test statistics that they get for their example for my dataset? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to data() is supposed to be used for package-supplied datasets, not for ones you import. I think you are misinterpreting a *warning*.

```
data(Cattle,package='npmv')
Warning message:
In data(Cattle, package = "npmv") : data set ‘Cattle’ not found
```

R reports both 'warnings' and 'errors' and I don't think yours is an error. I get no error when loading your data and running that function:

```
Cattle <- read.table(text=" Treatment Replicate Weight_Loss Persistent Head_Size Salebarn_Q
    'LA 200'         1       17.90      14.10     14.25        1.0
    'LA 200'         2       19.30      15.30      2.56        1.0
    'LA 200'         3       19.50      16.82      5.80        1.5
    'LA 200'         4       18.94      12.70      7.51        1.5
    Excede         1       19.60      11.20     14.52        1.0
    Excede         2       19.50      10.54      9.83        1.0
    Excede         3       19.10      10.83      3.82        0.5
    Excede         4       20.40      11.00      0.04        1.0
   Micotil         1       17.30      14.29      1.62        1.0
   Micotil         2       20.00      11.65      0.13        3.0
   Micotil         3       18.10      10.89      2.41        0.0
   Micotil         4       19.50      12.43      5.93        2.0
    Zoetis         1       18.50      25.48     10.08        1.0
    Zoetis         2       17.60      20.12     11.93        1.0
    Zoetis         3       19.70      23.29      7.93        2.5
    Zoetis         4       18.50      28.32     13.08        3.0", header=TRUE)
```

Here's the call

```
nonpartest(Weight_Loss|Persistent|Head_Size|Salebarn_Q~Treatment,data=Cattle,permreps=1000)

Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
$results
                                                  Test Statistic   df1     df2 P-value
ANOVA type test p-value                                    2.843 6.912 27.6479   0.023
McKeon approx. for the Lawley Hotelling Test                  NA    NA      NA      NA
Muller approx. for the Bartlett-Nanda-Pillai Test             NA    NA      NA      NA
Wilks Lambda                                                  NA    NA      NA      NA
                                                  Permutation Test p-value
ANOVA type test p-value                                              0.007
McKeon approx. for the Lawley Hotelling Test                            NA
Muller approx. for the Bartlett-Nanda-Pillai Test                       NA
Wilks Lambda                                                            NA

$releffects
        Weight_Loss Persistent Head_Size Salebarn_Q
Excede      0.71875    0.15625   0.50000    0.30469
LA 200      0.43750    0.59375   0.53125    0.53125
Micotil     0.45312    0.37500   0.23438    0.53125
Zoetis      0.39062    0.87500   0.73438    0.63281

Warning message:
In nonpartest(Weight_Loss | Persistent | Head_Size | Salebarn_Q ~  :
  Rank covariance matrix is singular, only ANOVA test returned
```

Comment: Very nice thanks a ton, I guess the mistake was in the object assignment somehow? When I copy and paste yours it works but when I did mine it did give me an actual error: "[1] "Error: Each group must have sample size of at least 2"
Warning messages:
1: In min(which(frame[, groupvar] == levels(frame[, groupvar])[i])) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(which(frame[, groupvar] == levels(frame[, groupvar])[i])) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf   "

Comment: If you only execute a `read.table` or other similar input statement, but do not assign it to an object name, then it basically disappears. Functions can only work on named objects. The situation is different with `save` and `load`. Any "save"-d objects retain their names and the names are immediately available without any further assignment after the `load` call executed in a subsequent session.

Comment: That makes sense, my object was just from reading the csv in so you're exactly right. Thanks a ton